# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have the following jar files

```
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-3.11.jar
poi-ooxml-3.11.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta2.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.11.jar
poi-excelant-3.11.jar
```

and i'm trying to read an excel(2007) worksheet. My code is as follows

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class AdaptiveControllers {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String excelFilePath = "test.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
            }
            System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();
}

}
```

but when I run the code in eclipse I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:427)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:162)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:263)
at AdaptiveControllers.main(AdaptiveControllers.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:46)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You have a versions mix of `poi-3.11` and `poi-3.15-beta2`. Don't do that. See [FAQ 19](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204).

Comment: @AxelRichter    Thankyou! I replaced poi-3.15-beta2 with poi-3.11-beta2 and it works