# Apache POI poi-ooxml:4.0.0 throws org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

**Context:**

Trying to open XLSX file using Apache POI's poi & poi-ooxml 4.0.0 version jar's

**Issue:**

The program throws an error as shown below. I find this error when I use version 4.0.0, as I was able to open excel file using version 3.17 or earlier.

Hope the issue faced is clear & await inputs on how to fix this issue.

**Note:** Found some related queries but they relate to earlier versions of POI - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39719168/3127144) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45523290/3127144)

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Open Excel XLSX file
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
            ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            System.out.println(workBook);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.0'
//    Tried adding the below jar's as well but dint help
//    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.2'
//    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.0.0'
//    compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.0.1'
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:648)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at main.Test.main(Test.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same issue trying to use poi 4.0.1.

Adding `compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4"` fixed the issue for me

all my dependencies:

```
compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.1"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.1"
```

Comment: Fantastic. Indeed the schemas 1.4 version made the difference. The error was coming when version 1.3 was being used.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your POI version to 4.1.0 or greater.

In a pom.xml it would be like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```