# Error with xlsx file in android studio using Apache poi

Tags: java, android, namespaces, apache-poi

With what that error can be connected: `org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: error: The 'namespace-prefix' feature is not supported while the 'namespaces' feature is enabled.` ?

I'm just trying to understand to how can I work with Excel file and that error stuck me so much.
In my Excel sheet I have one row and 2 columns, in the first column - some number, in the second - some text.

My MainActivity and implementation's code below.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    TextView TextView;
    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView.setText("SomeText");

        try {

            AssetManager am=getAssets();
            InputStream is=am.open("MyTest.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            XSSFSheet mySheet = book.getSheet("0");
            XSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(0);

            if(row.getCell(0).getCellType() == CellType.STRING){
                String name = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                Log.d(TAG,"/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////name : " + name);
            }
            if(row.getCell(0).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC){
                double date = row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                Log.d(TAG,"/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////date : : " + date);
            }

            book.close();
            TextView.setText("SomeText after all");

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolg "+String.valueOf(ex));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation's:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation files('libs\\commons-codec-1.15.jar')
implementation files('libs\\commons-compress-1.21.jar')
implementation files('libs\\commons-logging-1.2.jar')
implementation files('libs\\curvesapi-1.06.jar')
implementation files('libs\\poi-5.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs\\poi-ooxml-5.1.0.jar')

implementation files('libs\\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar')
implementation files('libs\\xmlbeans-5.0.2.jar')
implementation files('libs\\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar')
implementation files('libs\\commons-io-2.11.0.jar')
implementation files('libs\\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar')
implementation files('libs\\poi-ooxml-lite-5.1.0.jar')

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Comment: Does [this question help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992755/apache-poi-poi-ooxml4-0-0-throws-org-apache-poi-ooxml-poixmlexception)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using latest version in module level Gradle.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3'<br>
  implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

download and integrate into your project
https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/releases

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).